# how @bean and @Autowired actually works?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

My configuration:

```
   @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoderBean() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    // @Autowired
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
```

this code works fine. But if I remove `@Autowired` from `passwordEncoder`, then I must add  `@Autowired` on the `configure` method. But this rules not apply on `authenticationManagerBean()` method. Can anyone explain ?

Comment: I think you should show more of the code to make this question better. Do you have a bean configuration .xml file or not?

Comment: "But this rules not apply on authenticationManagerBean() method" Of course, since you override it (cannot add PasswordEncoder as parameter)

Comment: I don't know exactly your goal with this approach, but you have two different passwordEncoder in your example.

The interface declaration (where you need to include the @Autowired) and one method that returns one BCryptPasswordEncoder instance (unused).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this URL https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture/
It seems that you Autowire AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth as a @Bean here.

Configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) so it will work in this case and passwordEncoder is also Autowired.

Comment: you are right. Spring Boot provides a default global AuthenticationManager. So why i need Autowired with PasswordEncoder but not need AuthenticationManager.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you use Spring annotations configuration,

If you don't add Spring annotations to method or field, Spring doesn't know it need to be initiated and therefore when used in Spring context ( also without initialize it outside Spring), objects will be null

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons you need to avoid storing the password in plaintext. based on this principle you have this option to encode your password.

In your example, you are using the *PasswordEncoder* interface:

```
.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
```

Using this approach you must inform one implementation. In Spring you can inject this implementation using @Autowired (in the declaration or like your code on the method that use your *PasswordEncoder* interface).

Just a question... Why you created one implementation?

```
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoderBean(){...
```

I think that this method can be replaced for your Autowired encode interface.